# Angular not clearing text input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I want to hide a div based on a click from a controller :

My HTML :

```
<div ng-controller ="myctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="emp in emps">
       <div class="myclass">
        <p> {{emp.name}} </p> 
          <span class="testclass" ng-click="showBox='true'" >Show</span><br>

          <div ng-show="showBox">
            <textarea rows="3" cols="50" ng-model="data.sometext"></textarea><br>
            <button ng-click = "testme(sometext)">Submit</button>
          </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the controller :

```
app.controller("myctrl", function($scope){

    $scope.data = {sometext : ""}  //DONT KNOW WHY I HAD TO DO LIKE THIS

    $scope.testme = function(sometext){
        console.log(sometext);
        $scope.data.sometext = "";  //THIS WORKS.
        $scope.showBox = false;     //THIS DOES NOT WORK.
        $scope.showBox = 'false';   //THIS DOES NOT WORK.
        HOW TO HIDE THE DIV  
}    
});
```

So When I click `Show`, the `textarea` is shown. When I click the button, the text area becomes empty. Like I want. But the div is not hidden. I want to hide the div when the button is clicked. Tried to make the `ng-show` `false` but its not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be using the [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive on your span element.

From the [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) documentation:

> The ngModel directive binds an input, select, textarea (or custom form
>   control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is
>   created and exposed by this directive.

I have changed your code to make it a little clearer to demonstrate. The code now uses the controller as syntax to make it clearer where the data belongs to and the span has been changed to a button. See the [AngularJS example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#example) of the controller as syntax and the benefits of doing so.

The following demonstrates:

1) When you click the show button, showText property of that emp is set to true.

2) Because the scope has been updated, the [`$digest`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) cycle is called and the expression within the [`ngShow`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) directives on your `div` tags are evaluated. Those with the `showText` property of the emp set to true will evaluate true and the `div` element containing your `textarea` then shows.

3) When you click the "Submit" button your `testme` function on your `controller` is called, passing in the binded value from the `textarea` [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive held in `MyCtrl.data.sometext` and the emp so we can change it's properties. A `text` property of the emp is set to the input and the `showText` property is set back to false so the textarea is then hidden again.

```js
// app.js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', []);

})();

// my.controller.js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app').controller("MyController", MyController);

  MyController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MyController($scope) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.emps = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "John Doe"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Jane Smith"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Jack Jones"
      }
    ];

    // expose the testme function to the view
    vm.testme = testme;

    function testme(input, emp) {
      
      // get the index of the employee
      var index = vm.emps.indexOf(emp);
      
      // set the employee text to the input
      vm.emps[index].text = input;
      
      // set showText to false
      vm.emps[index].showText = false;

    }

  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController as MyCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="emp in MyCtrl.emps">

    <div class="myclass">

      <p>{{emp.name}} </p>
      <p>{{emp.text}}</p>
      <p>
        <button ng-click="emp.showText = !emp.showText">{{emp.showText ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}}</button>
      </p>

      <div ng-show="emp.showText">
        <textarea rows="3" cols="50" ng-model="MyCtrl.data.sometext"></textarea><br>
        <button ng-click="MyCtrl.testme(MyCtrl.data.sometext, emp); MyCtrl.data.sometext = ''">Submit</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I sincerely apologize. I did not include the `ng-repeat` in my original question. I edited the question. Your solution works perfectly fine with a standalone `span` and `div` but not when nested in a `ng-repeat`. Don't know why. Please have a look at the edits. Once again. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Somename I have now updated it to use the emp as the driver for showing/hiding the textarea

Comment: This works perfect! Exactly what Im looking for. Can I try to code this without `vm` and using simple `$scope`? And without using the `index` as  i've heard it causes wrong `indexes` when using `filter` in `ng-repeat`? Many thanks.

Comment: Sure you can, just replace `vm` with `$scope` in your controller and remove the `MyCtrl` prefixes in the view. Have a play around with the code and experiment :)

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code, like use ng-model in the span. Here you have a working jsfiddle with some changes

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <span class="testclass" ng-click="showBox='true'">Show</span><br>

  <div ng-show="showBox">
    <textarea rows="3" cols="50" ng-model="data.sometext"></textarea><br>
    <button ng-click="testme(sometext)">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var ang = angular.module('myApp', []);

ang.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    sometext:""
  };

  $scope.testme = function(text){
    $scope.showBox = false;
  }
}]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lonking/qo7bngmq/

Comment: I sincerely apologize. I did not include the `ng-repeat` in my original question. I edited the question. Please have a look at the edits. Once again. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Somename Sometimes it happens, dont worry. I saw it too late, but the selected answer works fine, so use it :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi could you try initialising $scope.showBox = false; and also ng-click="showBox=true" and not ng-click="showBox='true'" as it is a string form. Your code is correct to an extent also try hitting control save on your text editor just might work :) .